# why there are many utf8 in the output of locale command?

Tags: linux, utf-8

when I execute locale command on my ubuntu machine, I got:

```
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8

...
```

Why there are so many utf8 ? 
Wiki said that "UTF-8  is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set". so why locale give different utf8? 
what is the different between each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locales are much more. Each of these entries is a UTF-8-based locale with more parameters: Number format(`1,234,567` vs `1.234.567` vs `1 234 567`), currency symbols, date formats, srt orders, and other local conventions of textual data. Almost all use the same encoding, namely UTF-8.

Comment: I'm going with fastest. Thanks all!

Comment: @camino I wasn't the fastest :D Thanks anyway. Eric had a basic answer first and completed it in a subsequent edit.

Comment: I didn’t notices that, I give Eric an extra credit :) Thanks all again!

Answer (score 1):

The locale is more than just an encoding

> Locales customize programs to your language and country.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

> Regional settings, such as date and time formats, as well as language, sort order, etc. are specified in files called locales.  A locale contains the rules specifying how dates and times are formatted, amongst other settings.

http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/